# Given that x is a constructible number, how does one prove that 1/x is constructible?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given that *x* is a constructible number, how does one prove that 1/*x* is constructible? Moreover, what might be one's train of thought when coming up with the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unit length.

Create a triangle with sides 1 and x.
The other side doesn't matter.

Then create a similar triangle
with the side
corresponding to x
having length 1.

The side corresponding to 1
then has length 1/x.